# Linear regression with non-linear constrained coefficients

Tags: r, regression, linear-model, constrained-regression

I have a simple 3-factor linear model: $y = a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + a_3x_3$, and I want the coefficients to satisfy $a_3 = a_1 \times a_2$. How should I code it in R?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of thinking of it as a linear regression subject to a non-linear constraint, you can get a solution by non-linear least squares (nls() in R):

```
N <- 1000
x1 <- rnorm(N)
x2 <- rnorm(N)
x3 <- rnorm(N)

a1 = 2
a2 = 3

y <- a1*x1 + a2*x2 + a1*a2*x3 + rnorm(N)

nls(y ~ -1 + a1*x1 + a2*x2 + a1*a2*x3, start = list(a1 = 0, a2 = 0), trace = T)

50722.64 :  0 0
2064.18 :  2.145276 2.859526
1995.486 :  2.002083 2.960784
1995.284 :  2.004799 2.963501
Nonlinear regression model
model: y ~ -1 + a1 * x1 + a2 * x2 + a1 * a2 * x3
data: parent.frame()
 a1    a2 
2.005 2.964 
residual sum-of-squares: 1995

Number of iterations to convergence: 3 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 7.22e-06
```

Comment: thanks for your help. If the goodness of fit is needed in this case, is there a way to get the R-Squared value, AIC and BIC?

Comment: As I see nls() doesn't calculate those statistics for you, but it gives you the residual sum of squared RSS (see above), and that should be everything you need to calculate R-Squared (see wikipedia page), for AIC ($AIC = n \times ln(RSS/n) + 2k + constant$) (see wikipedia page again), etcetera.

Comment: I just realized that if $y$ and $x1,x2,x3$ are from one time series $y_t$, the model is simply $arima(y, order = c(1, 0, 0), seasonal = list(order = c(1, 0, 0), period = n))$. With "CSS" method, I got the same coefficients with nls(), whist the intercept is way different. Do you know why?

Comment: Uhmmm, I don't know but notice that in my code the intercept is missing, did you add it? Did you try to use simulated data to check whether arima() or nls() is giving you the right intercept? Maybe you could open another question in order to address that problem.

Comment: user3060702 - given that the plethora of usual relationships between things that exist for $R^2$ in linear models don't necessarily apply for nonlinear models, what definition of $R^2$ do you seek here?

Answer (score 1):

In principle, I believe you can do this using `lavaan` (short for "latent variable analysis"), which can fit general linear models with nonlinear equality constraints (see page 32 of [this PDF, "lavaan: An R package for structural equation modeling."](http://users.ugent.be/~yrosseel/lavaan/lavaanJSSpreview.pdf)). However, I haven't yet been able to get it to work on simulated data without encountering a non-positive definite matrix error. Anyway, the code would look something like this:

```
y=~a*x+b*w+c*z
c==a*b
```